# Why does the word strand mean "distress"?

Tags: meaning

How come a word that has a meaning of "a line of something"(strand) could sometimes mean "getting in the distress situation"?

Comment: Can you give us the complete sentence where you saw this used?

Comment: @stangdon "Would you give me a strand of your hair?" and "The ship was stranded off".

Comment: Etymonline mentions three senses of the word; two are apparently from unrelated roots. https://www.etymonline.com/word/strand

Comment: I think the connection is "a beach is a long skinny thing; a hair or thread is a long skinny thing, so they are both *a strand*; a ship is stuck if it washes up on the beach, or *is stranded*."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strand has several meanings and should not be mixed up.

From Google Dictionary,

> strand1
> /strand/
> verb
> verb: strand; 3rd person present: strands; past tense: stranded; past participle: stranded; gerund or present participle: stranding
> 1.
> leave (someone) without the means to move from somewhere.

> strand2
> /strand/
> noun
> noun: strand; plural noun: strands
> a single thin length of something such as thread, fibre, or wire, especially as twisted together with others.